# Golang How to read input filename in Go

Tags: file, go, readfile

I would like to run my go file on my `input.txt` where my go program will read the `input.txt` file when I type in go run command ie:

```
go run goFile.go input.txt
```

I don't want to put `input.txt` in my `goFile.go` code since my go file should run on any input name not just `input.txt`.

I try `ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)` but I need to change my command to

```
go run goFile.go < input.txt
```

I only use package `fmt`, `os`, `bufio` and `io/ioutil`. Is it possible to do it without any other packages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please take a look at the package documentation of [`io/ioutil`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/) which you are already using.

It has a function exactly for this: [`ReadFile()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile)

```
func ReadFile(filename string) ([]byte, error)
```

Example usage:

```
func main() {
    // First element in os.Args is always the program name,
    // So we need at least 2 arguments to have a file name argument.
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("Missing parameter, provide file name!")
        return
    }
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't read file:", os.Args[1])
        panic(err)
    }
    // data is the file content, you can use it
    fmt.Println("File content is:")
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firs you check for the provided argument. If the first argument satisfy the condition of an input file, then you use the `ioutil.ReadFile` method, providing parameter the `os.Args` result.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 1 {
        fmt.Println("Usage : " + os.Args[0] + " file name")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot read the file")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // do something with the file
    fmt.Print(string(file))
}
```

Another possibility is to use:

```
f, err := os.Open(os.Args[0])
```

but for this you need to provide the bytes lenght to read:

```
b := make([]byte, 5) // 5 is the length
n, err := f.Read(b)
fmt.Printf("%d bytes: %s\n", n, string(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

For running .go file from command-line by input parameter like file (for example abc.txt).We need use mainly  **os, io/ioutil, fmt**  packages. Additionally for reading command line parameters we use
**os.Args** Here is example code

```
package main
 import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "io/ioutil"
)
func main()  {
fmt.Println(" Hi guys  ('-') ")
input_files := os.Args[1:]
//input_files2 := os.Args[0];
//fmt.Println("if2 : ",input_files2)
if len(input_files) < 1{
fmt.Println("Not detected files.")
}else{
fmt.Println("File_name is : ",input_files[0])
content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(input_files[0])
if err != nil {
fmt.Println("Can't read file :", input_files[0],"Error : ",err)
}else {
fmt.Println("Output file content is(like string type) : \n",string(content))//string Output
fmt.Println("Output file content is(like byte type) : \n",content)//bytes Output
}
}
}
```

Args holds command line arguments, including the command as Args[0].
If the Args field is empty or nil, Run uses {Path}.
In typical use, both Path and Args are set by calling Command.
Args []string
function. This function return back array on string type [https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile).Args hold the command-line arguments, starting with the program name. In this case short way to take filename from command-line is this functions **os.Args[1:]** . And  here is output

```
elshan_abd$ go run main.go abc.txt
Hi guys  ('-')
File_name is :  abc.txt
Output file content is(like string type) : 
aaa
bbb
ccc
1234
Output file content is(like byte type) : 
[97 97 97 10 98 98 98 10 99 99 99 10 49 50 51 52 10]
```

Finally we need for reading content file this function 
`func ReadFile(filename string) ([]byte, error)`  source is  https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile